# How to SELECT FROM 3 columns and GROUP as one without duplicate entries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have 3 columns with game genre names... looks like:

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| genre1      | genre2      |  genre3  |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| Action      |   Shooter   |          |
| Action      |             |          |
| Sport       |             |          |
| Adventure   |             |          |
| Action      |  Adventure  | Strategy |
```

My question is, how to get all the names in one column for output without duplicates, like:

```
Action
Shooter
Sport
Adventure
Strategy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) operator will eliminate duplicates.

```
SELECT genre1 AS genre FROM YourTable
UNION
SELECT genre2 AS genre FROM YourTable
UNION
SELECT genre3 AS genre FROM YourTable
```